# Bootstrap-table data-show-column in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table

I would like to be able to choose with a dropdown, which columns are shown in my table in React.

Something like in this example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/

I would like to use the "column" dropdown button in a toolbar. But I can't use it in React..

I tried to do something like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/wenyi/uzgkzjcp/7/light/

But I get this error message:

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-table/package.json
Module parse failed: ..\node_modules\bootstrap-table\package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (....\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
 @ ./~/bootstrap-table/Gruntfile.js 104:22-47

Someone has an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Show what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error for bootstrap-table. To solve it, I had to edit ~/bootstrap-table/package.json.

There is a line

> "main":"Gruntfile.js",

I changed this to

> "main": "./dist/bootstrap-table.js",

I don't fully understand, but I suspect Gruntfile.js is designed to be run on the server-side, and we're running it on the client-side.